# pyspark : NameError: name 'spark' is not defined

Tags: apache-spark, machine-learning, pyspark, distributed-computing, apache-spark-ml

I am copying the pyspark.ml example from the official document website:
http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.ml.html#pyspark.ml.Transformer

```
data = [(Vectors.dense([0.0, 0.0]),), (Vectors.dense([1.0, 1.0]),),(Vectors.dense([9.0, 8.0]),), (Vectors.dense([8.0, 9.0]),)]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ["features"])
kmeans = KMeans(k=2, seed=1)
model = kmeans.fit(df)
```

However, the example above wouldn't run and gave me the following errors:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-28-aaffcd1239c9> in <module>()
      1 from pyspark import *
      2 data = [(Vectors.dense([0.0, 0.0]),), (Vectors.dense([1.0, 1.0]),),(Vectors.dense([9.0, 8.0]),), (Vectors.dense([8.0, 9.0]),)]
----> 3 df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ["features"])
      4 kmeans = KMeans(k=2, seed=1)
      5 model = kmeans.fit(df)

NameError: name 'spark' is not defined
```

What additional configuration/variable needs to be set to get the example running?

Comment: change to sqlContext works. thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Since you are calling [createDataFrame()](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.2/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.SQLContext.createDataFrame), you need to do this:

```
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(data, ["features"])
```

instead of this:

```
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ["features"])
```

`spark` stands there as the `sqlContext`.

---

In general, some people have that as `sc`, so if that didn't work, you could try:

```
df = sc.createDataFrame(data, ["features"])
```

Comment: If I use sc, it doesn't work. But if I use sqlContext, it works. Is this expected?

Comment: Yes @Edamame, it all depends on how you import stuff.. :)

Answer (score 92):

You can add

```py
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql.session import SparkSession
sc = SparkContext('local')
spark = SparkSession(sc)
```

to the begining of your code to define a SparkSession, then the `spark.createDataFrame()` should work.

Answer (score 38):

[Answer by 率怀一](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43231461/6188720) is good and will work for the first time.
But the second time you try it, it will throw the following exception :

```py
ValueError: Cannot run multiple SparkContexts at once; existing SparkContext(app=pyspark-shell, master=local) created by __init__ at <ipython-input-3-786525f7559f>:10
```

There are two ways to avoid it.

1) Using `SparkContext.getOrCreate()` instead of `SparkContext()`:

```py
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql.session import SparkSession
sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate()
spark = SparkSession(sc)
```

2) Using `sc.stop()` in the end, or before you start another SparkContext.

Answer (score 3):

If it errors you regarding other open session do this:

```
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql.session import SparkSession
sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate();

spark = SparkSession(sc)
scraped_data=spark.read.json("/Users/reihaneh/Desktop/nov3_final_tst1/")
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to import the spark as following if you are using python then it will create
a spark session but remember it is an old method though it will work.

```
from pyspark.shell import spark
```

Answer (score 0):

The situation may be different now..

from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

..

spark = SparkSession(sc)

works.

Comment: This question has already been adequately answered and you must use a code block in your reply.