# name spark is not defined

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

Trying to follow the spark tutorial but get the following error -

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/quick-start.html

"name 'spark' is not defined"

```
Using Python version 2.6.6 (r266:84292, Nov 22 2013 12:16:22)
SparkContext available as sc.
>>> import pyspark
>>> textFile = spark.read.text("README.md")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'spark' is not defined
```

This is how I start it -

```
./bin/pyspark --master local[*]
```

Comment: What is your spark version ?

Comment: Version - spark 1.0.1

Comment: Please update to 1.6 if not 2.0+. It'll be an easier learning experience. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your spark version is 1.0.1 you should not use the tutorial for version 2.2.0. There are major changes between these versions.

On this website you can find the [Tutorial for 1.6.0](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.0/quick-start.html) .

Following the 1.6.0 tutorial you have to use `textFile = sc.textFile("README.md")`  instead of `textFile = spark.read.text("README.md")`.