# name 'spark' is not defined

Tags: python-3.x, pyspark, spyder

I'm running the below code and getting the error(name 'spark' is not defined). I have installed still getting error and help me to resolve this error.

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([
    (1, 144.5, 5.9, 33, 'M'),
    (2, 167.2, 5.4, 45, 'M'),
    (3, 124.1, 5.2, 23, 'F'),
    (4, 144.5, 5.9, 33, 'M'),
    (5, 133.2, 5.7, 54, 'F'),
    (3, 124.1, 5.2, 23, 'F'),
    (5, 129.2, 5.3, 42, 'M'),
], ['id', 'weight', 'height', 'age', 'gender'])
```

Comment: See this page : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39541204/pyspark-nameerror-name-spark-is-not-defined

Answer (score 4):

try this :

```
from pyspark.sql.session import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
```